# Group by com Python[Nympy ou Pandas] - Trazer a 1º linha e ultima Linha por Data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, group-by

Boa tarde colegas do forum. Estou com uma dificuldade em trazer a 1º linha e a ultima linha agrupado por data. POrém, gostaria de trazer esses dados no formato que estou utilizando o group By na soma ou count. Segue exemplo abaixo.
Abaixo segue o código que consegui fazer

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"DATA": ['28/10','28/10','29/10','29/10','29/10','30/10','30/10','30/10','31/10','31/10'],
               "MAXIMA":['21','27','25','29','24','27','28','32','29','25'],
               "MINIMA":['6','12','18','9','5','8','24','18','15','10'],
               "Close":['17','24','22','10','21','25','26','30','18','10']})
df2 = df[["DATA","MAXIMA","MINIMA"]]
df2['maxDia'] = df.groupby('DATA')["MAXIMA"].transform(np.max)
df2['minDia'] = df.groupby('DATA')["MINIMA"].transform(np.min)
df2 = df2.drop(["MAXIMA","MINIMA"], axis=1)
df2 = df2.drop_duplicates()
df2.head()
```

DATA    maxDia  minDia
0   28/10   27  12
2   29/10   29  18
5   30/10   32  18
8   31/10   29  10

Ai coloquei para trazer o first e last, mas esta dando erro. Será que é outro nome? OU outra forma e manter o padrão do código?  Muito obrigado.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"DATA": ['28/10','28/10','29/10','29/10','29/10','30/10','30/10','30/10','31/10','31/10'],
           "MAXIMA":['21','27','25','29','24','27','28','32','29','25'],
           "MINIMA":['6','12','18','9','5','8','24','18','15','10'],
           "Close":['17','24','22','10','21','25','26','30','18','10']})
df2 = df[["DATA","MAXIMA","MINIMA"]]
df2['maxDia'] = df.groupby('DATA')["MAXIMA"].transform(np.max)
df2['minDia'] = df.groupby('DATA')["MINIMA"].transform(np.min)  
**df2['abeDia'] = df.groupby('DATA')["FECHAMENTO"].transform(np.first)**
**df2['fecDia'] = df.groupby('DATA')["FECHAMENTO"].transform(np.last)**
df2 = df2.drop(["MAXIMA","MINIMA"], axis=1)
df2 = df2.drop_duplicates()
df2.head()
```

ERRO: AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'first'

Comment: O comando `first` pertence ao pandas, e não ao numpy. Apenas mude o seu `np.first` para `"first"`(como string) que irá funcionar :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A funçao `first` pertence ao pandas, e não ao numpy. Apenas mude o seu `np.first` para `"first"`(como string) que irá funcionar :)

```
df2 = df[["DATA","MAXIMA","MINIMA"]]
df2['maxDia'] = df.groupby('DATA')["MAXIMA"].transform(np.max)
df2['minDia'] = df.groupby('DATA')["MINIMA"].transform(np.min)  
df2['abeDia'] = df.groupby('DATA')["Close"].transform('first')
df2['fecDia'] = df.groupby('DATA')["Close"].transform('last')
df2 = df2.drop(["MAXIMA","MINIMA"], axis=1)
df2 = df2.drop_duplicates()
df2.head() 
#saida

    DATA    maxDia  minDia  abeDia  fecDia
0   28/10   27  12  17  24
1   28/10   27  12  17  24
2   29/10   29  18  22  21
3   29/10   29  18  22  21
4   29/10   29  18  22  21
```

Comment: Sensacional.  Muito obrigado pela ajuda.